# battery enclosures - i am not geting the hang of it

Tags: batteries, enclosure

I find it so hard to search for some casings for my board...

Why are the battery casings so rare ? I must be missing something.

Other questions

Will this case fit 2 AAA batteries ? how do I generally find out ?
http://www.tme.eu/en/details/g500b-bc/multipurpose-enclosures/gainta/g500bbc/

This one seems to be missing the battery compartment altogether. It only has a small cap for quick access to some batteries but nothing else. What would I need to buy together with this casing ? (looking to fit 2 AAA into it)
http://www.tme.eu/en/details/z-55/multipurpose-enclosures/kradex/z55/

Comment: This is off-topic, as it is asking for a place to find a product, but have you looked on Digikey or any other distributor? Digikey has many enclosures with battery compartments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had similar troubles, and now use small metal rods (slightly thinner than a bicycle spoke) inserted into plexiglass I had cut at a hw store. I secure the joints and rods with superglue. I build compartments into boxes with this, and sometimes the boxes themselves. Plexiglass can be filed, sawed and cut precisely, and I imagine it's possible to get sheets of ABS plastic, which would be easier to work with.

If you must have casings, I've no problem finding them on e.g. ebay ('aaa battery case 3v'), they just aren't suitable to put inside boxes unless you go commando with a hobby knife. For my own (admittedly ugly) battery holders, I use thin alu/copper plates, a few springs (not galvanized). Usually just pop the springs out of pens that have run out of ink... Have to check if they conduct well, but it's usually ok.

Answer (score 2):

You will generally have to look at the manufacturer's documentation to get the real details of enclosures (or almost anything else).

Your first link, to the Gainta box, has a [link to a technical information document](http://www.tme.eu/en/Document/f2429736893db4397f93609eb3b5f995/G500.pdf) which states that there are options for a battery compartment that can holds 2 or 4 AA cells. According to that same document they have the available metal clips for the battery compartment contacts which have to be ordered separately. From the looks of it these contacts are designed to mount to one end of circuit board.